# What element is on this image?

Tags: android

Please look at the image.

[image]

What are the three elements at the bottom of the screen (about, help, settings)? Are these Buttons inside tabview?

Comment: when does it appear ? when you press on menu button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a simple `LinearLayout` with three `Button`s.